# What's the best way to mount a shelf below existing cabinets?

Tags: cabinets, shelving

We've raised all the cabinets in our kitchen all the way to the ceiling, and the plan is to build an open shelf to hang beneath it.

Like so:

[image]

I'm trying to decide what the best way to approach this would be. First of all, what type of wood should I get (I don't intend on making the shelve as beefy as pictured, unless it is advisable), and how can I construct them while being pretty minimalist about the design?

My first thought is build a shelf with a top and bottom biscuit jointed together, and fasten that to the bottom of the cabinets. I've never actually constructed cabinets before, so I'm a little slow on the planning part of this project.

Comment: Adding shelves is a matter of design, look and taste. You could make it match your cabinets, you could make it connect to them as well. You could also use decorative shelf hangers and use a floating design, either laminated wood, glass, or solid wood. Easiest is to use the shelf hangers. They come in all kinds of shapes, sizes and capabilities of weight handling.

Comment: @JeffCates The design is as shown above. My wife wants them to look like those shelves.

Comment: Attaching them will take some carpentry skills. As for materials, solid wood would be best. Attaching to the cabinet will be the trick. A biscuit joint won't hold the weight of what will be on the shelf. When they build those cabinets, the side is all one piece. You will need to use a hidden brace or bracket to connect the cabinet and shelf, one that can support the weight requirement.